# Selenium Webdriver: DragAndDrop out of screen

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium Webdriver to perform drag-and-drop in this way:

```
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.dragAndDrop(queryHelper.findElementByCss(startSelector), queryHelper.findElementByCss(endSelector));
builder.perform();
```

So, right now, `endSelector` element is out of screen, so screen scrolled down to `endSelector`, but drag and drop action failed.

Anyone knows how to add delay before drop in action perform, or any other way to solve problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try breaking the drag & drop process up a little, like this...

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(draggableElement)
                       .moveToElement(targetElement)
                       .release(draggableElement)
                       .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: It still didn't fix the problem.  It looks like that it need some delay before release, because the page has been move to the location of endElement, but moving is not succeed.  So would adding delay before release solve the problem, if yes, how can i add delay in the middle of action before build?

Comment: I solve the problem by adding another Action move=builder.moveToElement(targetElement).build; move.perform(); dragAndDrop.perform();